# errors while installing frama-c in cygwin

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to install frama-c in cygwin and get the following errors but I can't interpret them. Can you help me interpreting them or give me a link to where I get the information?

```
Preparing    Wp-Coq Sources
Uncaught exception: Util.UserError("_", _)
Makefile:49: recipe for target `depend' failed
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
src/wp/Makefile:285: recipe for target `.make-wpcoqs' failed
make: *** [.make-wpcoqs] Error 2
```

note that coqc and ocaml are both the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Coq 8.4 by any chance? I had something very similar happen to me, and my issue was the lack of the option `-coqlib <your Coq installation directory>` when Coq is not installed in the standard directory in the PATH. There used to be a specific error message in Coq 8.3, but it seems to have disappeared in Coq 8.4.

If you can find the line in the Makefile which runs the `coqdep` command, and replace it with something like `coqdep -coqlib ~/coq84pl1` (replacing `~/coq84pl1` with your Coq installation directory), it could work. But you would also need to add this flag to other Coq-related commands as well (`coqc`, for instance) or other issues might come up later.